# Bought a book and it says when you select an edge and press ctrl+alt+r it creates 2 parallel edges but nothing happens

Tags: edges, shortcut

he calls it "edge offset tool"

Comment: maybe they're talking about ctrl R which create an edge loop (or several if you press the + button or scroll)

Comment: When in doubt you can use the free search hitting "space" key: inserting "edge offset" points you to the command and its shortcut

Answer (score 2):

They've got the default shortcut wrong. It's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>**Shift**</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, which creates two loops on either side of the selected loop, interpolated between it and the ones on either side.

You can hit <kbd>E</kbd> while sliding the new loops to make them parallel either to the original loop, or the ones which bound it on either side. <kbd>F</kbd> flips which. Hitting <kbd>E</kbd> again returns to interpolation.